# Coalesce with count to get most occurred values in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, database

[Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6356a/6)

I'm using two tables, `model` and `variation`, to deal with some device series' special versions that have some slightly different attributes, like a mobile series is black in case color but its special edition uses gold as the color. I'm trying to make a query to pull in some average stats like price,speed as well as find out what material and cpu are mostly featured in the products.

My expected result should be like this:

```
AVG_SPEED   AVG_PRICE   MOST_USED_MATERIAL  MOST_USED_CPU
6375        1200        Gold                Intel
```

But the query that I've come up with gave me this result:

```
AVG_SPEED   AVG_PRICE   MOST_USED_MATERIAL  MOST_USED_CPU
6375        1200        Gold                (null)
```

Can anyone show me how to get the right values for `Most_used_material` and `most_used_cpu`?

I also want  to know if it's necessary to use a sub-query for each field (`material` and `cpu`) to get the most occured values. In my real situation I have a few more fields that I want to get the most occured values. Is there a way to optimize the query?

Query:

```
SELECT AVG(coalesce(v.speed,m.speed)) AS avg_speed,
AVG(m.price) AS avg_price,
 (SELECT v.material 
   FROM version v
   INNER JOIN model m ON v.model_id = m.model_id
   ORDER BY COUNT(coalesce(v.material,m.material)) 
   DESC LIMIT 0,1
 ) AS most_used_material,

 (SELECT v.cpu 
   FROM version v
   INNER JOIN model m ON v.model_id = m.model_id
   ORDER BY COUNT(coalesce(v.cpu,m.cpu)) 
   DESC LIMIT 0,1
 ) AS most_used_cpu

FROM version v 
INNER JOIN model m ON v.model_id = m.model_id
```

Table

```
CREATE TABLE version
    (`version_id` int,`model_id` int,`speed` int,`cpu` varchar(10),`material`varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO version
    (`version_id`,`model_id`,`speed`,`cpu`,`material`)
VALUES
    (1,1,6000,NULL,'Gold'),
    (2,2,NULL,NULL,NULL),
    (3,3,NULL,'AMD',NULL),
    (4,3,7000,NULL,NULL)
;

CREATE TABLE model
    (`model_id` int,`name` varchar(30),`speed` int,`price` int,`cpu` varchar(10),`material` varchar(30))
;

INSERT INTO model
    (`model_id`,`name`,`speed`,`price`,`cpu`,`material`)
VALUES
    (1,'A856',5500,1500,'Intel','Steel'),
    (2,'A820',6000,1300,'Intel','Gold'),
    (3,'X9',6500,1000,'Intel','Plastic')
;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
  ( SELECT COALESCE(v.cpu,m.cpu) AS cpu
      FROM version v
      JOIN model m ON v.model_id = m.model_id
     GROUP BY COALESCE(v.cpu,m.cpu)
     ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC LIMIT 1
  ) AS most_used_cpu
```

For testing, you can run that a separate SQL statement. That would allow you to add `COUNT(1)` to the SELECT list, and leave off the `LIMIT` clause. To include that as subquery in the SELECT list of the outer query, you'd need it like the query shown above, with only a single expression in the SELECT list and ensure that no more than one row is returned.

The query to get most used material would be similar.